# How to properly implement a search input with suggestions in django

Tags: django

I'm new to django, and i'm building a Q&A website, in the site there is a search input in the home page. What i want is to suggest related questions (by using only the title attribute of the Question entity) to the user while he is typing. After some research i found haystack (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/toc.html) but it seems to much, for my problem, is there a more simple way to implement this?

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, you don't need Haystack for that. As far as I know (which is not much, admittedly), even with Haystack you would need to implement the other parts yourself: an API endpoint and AJAX to consume it. See [an example](http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/).

Comment: I use in my site Awesomplete, for autocomplete purpose. Take a look: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/. You can fill autocomplete fields with your Question models titles. Also, you can redirect to the question if needed using `awesomplete-select` event.